# Scroll along path Paper.js

Tags: javascript, path, scroll, paperjs

Basically I want to scroll a object along path. I've seen several threads looking for similar solution not using paper.js but i was wondering if this possible with paper.js. Or can someone give me a working jsfiddle of object follow svg curve because I couldn't get any thing to work. I ultimately want to have a chain of divs follow the path.

```
// vars
var point1 = [0, 100];
var point2 = [120, 100];
var point3 = [120, 150];

// draw the line
var path = new Path();
path.add(new Point(point1), new Point(point2), new Point(point3));
path.strokeColor = "#FFF";
path.closed = true;

// draw the circle
var circle = new Path.Circle(0,100,4);
circle.strokeColor = "#FFF";

// target to move to
var target = point2;

// how many frame does it take to reach a target
var steps = 200;

// defined vars for onFrame
var dX       = 0;
var dY       = 0;

// position circle on path
circle.position.x = target[0];
circle.position.y = target[1];

function onFrame(event) {

    //check if cricle reached its target
    if (Math.round(circle.position.x) == target[0] && Math.round(circle.position.y) == target[1]) {
        switch(target) {
            case point1:
                target = point2;
                break;
            case point2:
                target = point3;
                break;
            case point3:
                target = point1;
                break;
        }

        // calculate the dX and dY
        dX = (target[0] - circle.position.x)/steps;
        dY = (target[1] - circle.position.y)/steps;

    }

    // do the movement
//circle.position.x += dX;
//circle.position.y += dY;
}
```

Here is the jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/J9xgY/12/

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is unclear — can you explain what you mean by "follow the path proportional using the scroll bar?" Also, keep in mind paper.js is not the best tool for moving external `div`s, but rather displaying graphics in the `canvas` element.

Comment: Basically i want to scroll a object along path.

Comment: You want to move the circle along the triangle-path?

Comment: yes through scrolling

Answer (score 0):

You can find a point along a path with `path.getPointAt(offset)` where `offset` is measured in points along the length of the path. If you can calculate the position of a slider along its track, you can multiply that by the path.length to get an offset.

You can do this with an HTML slider or with a canvas element, as shown here:

```
// vars
var point1 = [0, 100];
var point2 = [120, 100];
var point3 = [120, 150];

// draw the line
var path = new Path();
path.add(new Point(point1), new Point(point2), new Point(point3));
path.strokeColor = "#FFF";
path.closed = true;

// draw the circle
var circle = new Path.Circle(0,100,4);
circle.strokeColor = "#FFF";

// slider
var sliderLine = new Path(new Point(10,30.5), new Point(210, 30.5));
sliderLine.strokeColor = '#FFF';
var sliderKnob = new Path.Circle(new Point(10,30.5), 5);
sliderKnob.fillColor = '#FFF';

var sliderHit = false;

function onMouseDown(event) {
    if (event.item == sliderKnob) sliderHit = true;
}

function onMouseDrag(event) {
    if (sliderHit === true) {
        if (event.point.x > 10 && event.point.x < 210) {
            sliderKnob.position.x = event.point.x;
        }
        else if (event.point.x < 11) {
            sliderKnob.position.x = 10;
        }
        else if (event.point.x > 209) {
            sliderKnob.position.x = 210;
        }

        // Get offset and set circle position
        var percent = ( sliderKnob.position.x - 10 ) / 200;
        circle.position = path.getPointAt(path.length * percent);             
    }

}

function onMouseUp(event) {
    sliderHit = false;
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/J9xgY/13/

Click and drag the filled circle along the line to move the circle along the triangle.

Comment: Thank you! Although I wanted to use mouse wheel to control it, but I can take it from here.